# Using Groovy collection to exactly match the string format

Tags: java, string, jenkins, groovy, string-matching

I have a question about matching the exact string format using the groovy collection.

```
   def createPullRequest(projectSlug, repoSlug, title, description, sourceBranch, targetBranch) {
    //this is reading in the array with the user names
    def names = BitbutkcetUtil.getGroupUsers(teamName, activeOnly)

            def prResponse = this.steps.httpRequest(
                    acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                    authentication: this.userId,
                    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON',
                    httpMode: 'POST',
                    ignoreSslErrors: true,
                    quiet: true,
                    requestBody: """
                                {
                                    "title": "${title}",
                                    "description": "${description}",
                                    "state": "OPEN",
                                    "open": true,
                                    "closed": false,
                                    "fromRef": { "id": "${sourceBranch}" },
                                    "toRef": { "id": "${targetBranch}" },
                                    "locked": false,
                                    "reviewers": [
                                        //I want to replace this hardcoded names with the string values inside the array `names`
                                        { "user": { "name": "HardCoded1" } },
                                        { "user": { "name": "HardCoded2" } },
                                        { "user": { "name": "HardCoded3" } },
                                        { "user": { "name": "HardCoded4" } }
                                    ]
                                }
                            """,
                    responseHandle: 'STRING',
                    url: "https://bitbucket.absolute.com/rest/api/latest/projects/${projectSlug}/repos/${repoSlug}/pull-requests",
                    validResponseCodes: '200:299')
            def pullRequest = this.steps.readJSON(text: prResponse.content)
            prResponse.close()
            return pullRequest['id']
        }
```

What I want to do is I want to replace the `hardcoded` names inside the `reviewers` with the string elements inside the array `names`. I want to use the collection but I have to match the exact format

```
 { "user": { "name": "HardCoded1" } },
 { "user": { "name": "HardCoded2" } },
 { "user": { "name": "HardCoded3" } },
 { "user": { "name": "HardCoded4" } }
```

Right now, I have `[reviewers: names.collect{ [user: [name: it]] }]`, and it is outputting the following:

```
[reviewers:[[user:[name:name1]],
[user:[name:name2]],
[user:[name:name3]],
[user:[name:name4]]]]
```

How can I make it so that the output is in the following format?

```
    "reviewers": [
  //I want to replace this hardcoded names with the string values inside the array `names`
    { "user": { "name": "HardCoded1" } },
    { "user": { "name": "HardCoded2" } },
    { "user": { "name": "HardCoded3" } },
    { "user": { "name": "HardCoded4" } }
    ]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy/Jenkins - How to use a for loop inside the http request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891589/groovy-jenkins-how-to-use-a-for-loop-inside-the-http-request-body)

Comment: As stated in the answer to your previous question: banging strings together in the hope to end up with valid JSON is usually a bad idea.  Create the JSON from the whole map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is a result of calling `toString()` method on a list of map elements. For a valid JSON representation, you may pass a result of the `collect()` method to a  `JsonOutput.toJSON()`. Something like this:

```groovy
requestBody: """
            {
                "title": "${title}",
                "description": "${description}",
                "state": "OPEN",
                "open": true,
                "closed": false,
                "fromRef": { "id": "${sourceBranch}" },
                "toRef": { "id": "${targetBranch}" },
                "locked": false,
                "reviewers": ${JsonOutput.toJson(names.collect{ [user: [name: it]] })}
            }
        """
```

> `JsonOutput.toJSON()` may need script approval when it gets used for the first time in Jenkins Pipeline.

Comment: Thank you Szymon. However, `JsonOutput.toJson(names.collect{ [user: [name: it]] })` <- this whole line is treated as string from IDE which I think is due to three quote marks """. How do I make it recognizable by the IDE? Something like ${}?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It has to be wrapped inside `${...}` to be interpolated in the multiline GString. Updated the answer.